# Dispatch group notify not working

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I'm learning about GCD. And do a example like this: 
[image][click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf3JI.png)

I create function call three asynchronous block and use dispatch group to enter and leave each block
It seem group.enter(), group.leave() was called three times but the group not notify for me.

I want to ask for problem with this code, please help me.
Here is my code:

```
func myFunction() {
  let group = DispatchGroup()
  let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default)
  print("start")

  for i in 0..<3 {
    let count = 100/(i+1)
    var a = 0

    group.enter()
    print("enter queue \(i)")
    queue.async(group: group, execute: {
        for index in 0..<count {
            a = a + index
        }

        print("0..<\(count) with i: \(i)", a)
        group.leave()
        print("leave queue \(i)")
    })
  }

  group.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("after queue doing")
  }
}
```

Comment: Might make it easier if you put the code in a code block, then it can be cut and pasted so someone can easily try it, paste their modified version etc.

Comment: Thank for your advisor. I have put my code here

Comment: @phitướcnguyễnvăn Your code work fine in device, I think because your code make multiple thread modify the array at once, so it create some kind of internal error

Comment: Opps, It fun, haha. Thank for your test @Tj3n, I'm not test it on device because I cannot run it in playground.

Comment: If you makes 100 or 1000 loops, it will surely give you fatal error on devices,  both seems to not output error in playground though, but group.notify doesnt get called also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're executing asynchronous code on Playground then you need to enable indefinite execution by adding following code on top:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

I can test your code on Playground and it's working fine.